# Access JAR files loaded via Java Webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a java webstart application that is launched via a jnlp file. This JNLP file has several other JARs as dependencies and they are pulled over with the main jar (I can see them in the Java Resources Window on the client). These other JARs have "main" functions in them and I want to call them from the application that was initialized from the main jnlp. So a JNLP file calls LaunchingApp, Other.JAR, Other2.JAR. I want my LaunchingApp which has been started by the JNLP file to launch the other Jars in their own JVM using ProcessBuilder.command("java -jar path"). How do I reference the Other.jar and other2.jar from the java cache? Is it possible?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the other jars will even be standalone files.  I would include them inside your main .jar (yes, .jar files inside a .jar file), then use Class.getResourceAsStream to copy them to temporary files.  Alternatively, you could use [DownloadService2.getCachedResources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService2.html#getCachedResources(javax.jnlp.DownloadService2.ResourceSpec)) and copy the jar files from those resource specs to temporary files.

Comment: Unfortunately a requirement is to not have files on the file system.

Comment: Do they have to be separate processes?  Could you just start a new thread that calls the main class of a .jar file?